# CGPA for PhD. applications

Tags: graduate-admissions, gpa

I'm a computer science student in Turkey. I would like to apply a grad school in U.S., possible Columbia University or University of Michigan or University of Pennsylvania with scholarship. I will probably apply for Natural Language Processing.

My CGPA is 3.92 right now. I will go exchange (to NUS) next semester and I'm told that my GPA at exchange won't affect my CGPA. It seems that my CGPA over this semester will be my finalized CGPA to apply to schools.

This semester I took Intermediate Chinese I as an additional course (which is not on curriculum.) This is the 5th Chinese course I take and I just took it because I think it could be fancy on the transcript. Now that I thinking of studying at NLP, I think it would be beneficial. However there is strong possibility that I will take A- from that course, which drops my CGPA.

I also took linear algebra and differential equations and I have done pretty bad at the test so I will get something like B or B+ from it, which again drops my CGPA very badly. If I withdraw it, I can easily take A from this course when I retake it.

I have also other lessons which I do not know if I take A or A- so it is not certain that withdrawing from these courses helps my CPGA at not dropping below 3.90

So my question is, should I try to keep my CGPA as high as possible? Is it a good thing that I took Intermediate Chinese I and took A- of it? Is it better to withdraw from a Math course then take A or take B+ at the first try? Does CGPA matters that much?

Note: I still have no research experience but I will try to have some at exchange and in my home university at return. I hope they can get me good reference letters.

I know these are odd question that may not affect my future dramatically, but I have to make a decision. I appreciate your comments.

Note2: My current major CGPA (only CS courses) makes up to 3.82, I expect it to become 3.80 or 3.85. addin math courses except linear algebra makes it 3.90

Answer (score 2):

> Does CGPA matters that much?

I don't think so. Your current CGPA 3.92 is good enough. I think you have other things to worry if you want to get into the graduate schools you want to go. They are recommendation letters, GRE and TOEFL scores (if you are supposed to take TOEFL) and the research experience.

You do have some weakness in your major CGPA, however. Your math courses do not look too good. B/B+ grades for linear algebra and differential equations are simply below average unless you have other very strong math course grade to show on your transcript. How was the grade of your statistics? discrete math? Any other upper level math courses you have taken?

> Is it better to withdraw from a Math course then take A or take B+ at the first try?

Withdraw from those math courses may be too late now. I would suggest you to study much harder to get the grades above A- if all possible. "*I have done pretty bad at quiz so I will take smt like B or B+ from it*" is just an excuse to me. A few bad quiz scores could beat you?

You certainly need to take more advanced math courses after this semester. One possible way is to take more advanced math courses while at NSU (National Singapore University?). With your current math knowledge level, I am not sure you would be able to survive in the NLP programs you listed in the question even if you manage to get into one of them. The bottom line is, you need to strengthen your math.

Comment: They are (probability, discrete mathematics, calculus 1 and 2) all A. Forgot to mention, linear algebra and differential equations is one concerete course. It sounds funny bad Quiz really deter the letter grade much, each quiz with 0 pulls it down by 2.

Adding extra math courses never occured to me. Thank you! I think I should do that really.